# How to get xml fill to advance table using php

Tags: php, xml, dom, rss

I want to get xml from: http://sportsfeeds.bovada.lv/basic/ATP.xml to fill it to a special table like: http://sports.bovada.lv/sports-betting/tennis-atp.jsp

Current, I'm using DOMDocument to get it, but not ok, because it show not by order parent -> children.

```
   Time | Name | Odds

         John   3.65
         David  5.65
         John   3.65
         David  5.65
```

I want show such as:

Time

```
 3:50p | Name | Odds

         John   3.65
         David  5.65

 9:50a | Name | Odds
         John   3.65
         David  5.65
```

Like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XQuery to query your data.

For instance:

```
import module namespace http = "http://expath.org/ns/http-client";

let $schedule := http:send-request((), "http://sportsfeeds.bovada.lv/basic/ATP.xml")[2]/Schedule
for $event-type in $schedule/EventType
order by $event-type/@TS descending
return <div>
  <h1>{string($event-type/@NAME)}</h1>
  {
      for $event in $event-type/Date/Event
      return <div>
          <h2>{string($event/@NAME)}</h2>
      </div>
  }
</div>
```

You can try this example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#NBDPM72qey1mr4gSKRV1laxGnUc=
Instruction on how to install the PHP XQuery extension are available at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2011/12/27/PHP_Meets_XQuery